# How are each of the Dynasty Weapons obtained in Heroes VI?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

Judging by the achievements, there should be at least 25 of these things, but I'm not sure how to get more than a handful of them.

How does one unlock the various dynasty weapons?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there were so many!

Comment: Where did you come up with this list?  Is it possible that some of them are not available in the game yet?

Comment: @bwarner I got it from the [Heroes VI fan manual](http://forums.ubi.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/5861060878/m/5131057409). I don't see how they would have access to dynasty weapons that weren't already present in the game.

Comment: It seems to me that quite a bit of information that they have must be coming from decompiling the code, in which case it is possible that they're finding things that can't be accessed yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm making this community wiki: Please -- anyone with more information feel free to add it in!

### Might Affinity

**Angelic Alliance** - Complete Sidequest in Haven Campaign, Mission 4.

**Arachne** - Complete Sidequest in Necromancy Campaign, Mission 1.

**Assassin's Blade** - Buy from the Altar of Wishes. Requires Gold Dynasty Rank.

**Blade of Binding** - Complete Sidequest in Inferno Campaign, Mission 4

**Dragon Flame Tongue** - Wildcard (see below)

**Edge of Chaos** - Exclusive to preordering Heroes VI.

**Iron Feather** - Complete Sidequest in Haven Campaign, Mission 1.

**Malathua's Cleaver** - Complete Sidequest in Stronghold Campaign, Mission 2. (Blood mission)

**Perfect Silksword** - Wildcard (see below)

**Silksword of the Kirin** - Complete Sidequest in Sanctuary Campaign, Mission 2.

**Souldrinker** - Defeat an enemy hero as part of the main quest in Inferno Campaign, Mission 1.

**Sword of the Griffin** - Unlocked as part of the main quest in the Prologue Campaign.

**Sword of the Wolf** - Complete Sidequest in Stronghold Campaign, Mission 1.

**Sword of Whistlebone** - Complete Sidequest in Stronghold Campaign, Mission 2.

### Magic Affinity

**Batu's Totem** - Buy from Altar of Wishes. Requires Platinum Dynasty Rank.

**Heartrending Song** - Complete Sidequest in Haven Campaign, Mission 2.

**Soulreaver Staff** - Complete Sidequest in Necropolis Campaign, Mission 1.

**Staff of Asha's Eightfold** - Exclusive to the Heroes VI Deluxe Edition.

**Staff of Cleansing** - Exclusive to the Heroes VI Deluxe Edition.

**Staff of Sandro** - Complete Sidequest in Necropolis Campaign, Mission 3.

**Staff of Sar-Aggreth** - Wildcard (see below)

**Staff of the Tides** - Complete Sidequest in Sanctuary Campaign, Mission 1.

**The Oblivion** - Unlock from Uplay with Uplay points.

**Thunder Staff** - Complete Sidequest in Stronghold Campaign, Mission 2.

**Will of Urgash** - Buy from the Altar of Wishes. Requires Silver Dynasty Rank.

### Wildcard

You start with these artifacts unlocked if you own the complete edition of the game.

Answer (score 1):

2 Dynasty Weapons - Staff of Cleansing / Staff of Asha’s Eightfold are from Heroes VI Deluxe Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Malathua's Cleaver - Complete Sidequest in Stronghold Campaign, Mission 2. (Blood mission)

And thank you for this list ;)

Comment: Hi, Mathias, it looks like someone has edited this answer into the list for you!